# Why can't I have a colon in a Retrieve and Rank Solr query?

Tags: solr, ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

If I send a natural-language query to Retrieve and Rank (Solr), it will return an error if the query contains a colon. It seems to be attempting to interpret the word just prior to the colon as a field name.

Is there any way to prevent this, and are there other characters like this to which I should be aware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of characters you'll need to handle is at http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/plugin_query_syntax.shtml - it's at the bottom of the page under the heading "Reserved characters". (This also includes how to handle them)

These include:

> **Colon (:)**
>   Escape a colon in a query with a backslash.
>
> **Double quotation marks (")**
>   Escape double quotation marks in a query with a backslash in field queries.
>
> **Backslash (\) Escape character**
>   Escape a backslash in a query with another backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to escape the colon - if your Solr library isn't doing this for you automagically. Escaping uses `\` as in most other cases, so `foo\:bar` should work. Another option might be to wrap the value in quotes (`field:"foo:bar"`).